# Sort list from index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list with some values inputted from a text file. For example, lets say the list is

```
a = ["Hello 2476 hey!", "  hey 1534     hello!", "     2323"]
```

And I want to sort from the 6th index onward up to the tenth. I cannot figure out how to do this, even after searching SO a lot. All help is appreciated!

Comment: You could use sorted() on a slice and then assign the result back to the slice:

a[6:] = sorted(a[6:])

Comment: That is just outputting the whole string

Comment: Is the question to sort the strings by their 7th index in? Or to sort only items in the list after the 7th index?

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: `sorted(a, key=lambda s:s[6])` ?

Comment: The expected output would be ["  hey 1534     hello!", "     2323", Hello 2476 hey! ]

Comment: i would do `sorted(a, key=lambda s: s[6:])`, I expect OP intends to sort by the remainder of the string, not just the 6th index

Comment: These are partially working, however when tested with something like 200>, 200> will come higher than say 2000. I want to sort it between the 6 and the 10th index

Comment: It seems like you're trying to hack together using slicing and lexicographic sorting what [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) could already do

Comment: natsort looks great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['hack', 'the' , 'jack', 'with' , 'a' , 'mac' , 'on' , 'the' , 'last', 'monday']

result = a[:6]+sorted(a[6:10])
print(result)
```